# MongoDB atlas trigger - execution time limit exceeded

Tags: mongodb, algolia, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-realm

I'm testing out a trigger on MongoDB atlas which runs a Realm function for adding an object to Algolia index upon insertion to the MongoDB collection. In my case the record gets uploaded to Algolia index successfully but the function doesn't stop there and happens to exceed the time limit.

The docs mention that

> Function runtime is limited to 120 seconds

and that's the reason for the function to timeout

Here is my Realm function

```js
exports = function(changeEvent) {
  
  const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
  const client = algoliasearch(context.values.get('algolia_app'),context.values.get('algolia_key'));

  const index = client.initIndex("movies");


  changeEvent.fullDocument.objectID = changeEvent.fullDocument._id;
  delete changeEvent.fullDocument._id;
  index.saveObject(changeEvent.fullDocument)
  .then(({objectID}) => {
    console.log('successfully inserted: ',objectID);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

Here is the result I get on the logs

```
Logs:
[
  "successfully inserted:  61cf0a79c577393620dd8c80"
]
Error:
execution time limit exceeded
```

I even tried with `return` statements after the `console.log`s but still the same issue.

What I'm I doing wrong

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find a solution @cmgchess ?

Comment: @AndréFelipe nope I had to go with AWS EventBridge. I asked in their community forum as well but got no solution

Comment: Thanks @cmgchess it's a shame for MongoDB Realm

Comment: @AndréFelipe nice seems to work now. I saw your reply in Mongo forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was fixed by MongoDB team early this March as seen by https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/extremely-slow-execution-of-an-external-dependency-function/16919/27.

I tested with this code below and it worked perfect without any timeouts this time.
I made the function to be an async function. According to the logs it didn't even take 1 second to perform the indexing.

```js
exports = async function(changeEvent) {

  const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
  const client = algoliasearch(context.values.get('algolia_app'),context.values.get('algolia_key'));
  
  const index = client.initIndex("movies");

  changeEvent.fullDocument.objectID = changeEvent.fullDocument._id;
  delete changeEvent.fullDocument._id;
  try{
    const result = await index.saveObject(changeEvent.fullDocument);
    console.log(Date.now(),'successfully updated: ',result);
  }
  catch(e){
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

**Logs**
[image]